# Count Method on IEnumerable<IWebElement> does not return correct count

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, ienumerable

I am having an  issue where in the collection I can see 2 elements but count method on that collection returns count as only 1.

Workaround is to add a wait of 100 ms before count method and it  solves the issue but I am still not sure why it is happening.

I am using the following code to get the count :

```
IEnumerable<IWebElement> myEmptyElements = null;
var actualElementCount = 0;
myEmptyElements = allElements.Where(e => e.Text != "");

var expectedElementCount = table.RowCount;

//Adding this wait until we can find some better solution
//Thread.Sleep(100);
actualElementCount = myEmptyElements.Count();//this count returns less then number of items in the collection
```

Comment: When are you executing this code.  You should wait for selenium to load and run the page.

Comment: @RichardSchneider,the elemts are loaded properly and therefore I can see them in collection.Its the count method which returns the wrong number of items in collection.The allElements are passed from a separate function which first checks whether all elements are loaded properly and then populates it.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason(could be most probably) the element is taking longer to exist in the dom. I would use FindElements with proper selector and apply expected conditions and use `PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy` to wait the collection of the IWebElements. Please refer to the documentation [here](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/index.html)

Comment: the allElements is populated after waiting for the elemetns to be present and therefore the collections has the expected items.The issue which I dont understand is why allElements.count returns  less count   WaitFor(this By by)
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeoutInSeconds));        
            try { wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by));catch(catch expections) }
            
        }

Comment: So, if you put 100ms static wait it returns 2?